# Can I add custom CSS that will not affect the style of generated PDFs?

Tags: orbeon

The [Orbeon doc here](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#adding-your-own-css) shows how to add custom CSS like so:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.css.custom.uri.*.*"
    value="/config/acme.css"/>
```

This CSS affects the display in Form Runner as well as generated PDF versions of the forms. Is there a way to add custom CSS that will not affect the PDF?

I ask because I am using custom CSS that hides all sections by default and custom JavaScript to simulate navigation between sections via show/hide. Since all sections are hidden by default, I end up with a PDF that is empty except for the title.

If there is no easy way to do this, I can work around it. I am running Form Runner within the Proxy Portlet in Liferay so I can add my custom CSS to the Liferay theme. But if there is a way to do this with Orbeon that would be nice.

Comment: There is no separate CSS file as CSS allows you to indicate which rules apply for *print* vs. *screen*. If you just want your rules to apply just when the form is rendered "on the screen", try putting them in a `@media screen { ... }`. You'll let us know if this works for you. A lesser solution would be to have your rules always apply, and "reset them" with additional CSS inside a `@media print { ... }`.

Comment: @avernet Thanks, `@media screen { ... }` worked.

Comment: Perfect, and thank you for posting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per suggestion by @avernet I was able to resolve this issue by enclosing my custom CSS in `@media screen { ... }`.